# Toolbar covers page when clicked

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My Activity is built on layout `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` which contains **toolbar**. In the activity i have three webview which loads google.com, as soon i click the search-bar(to input the keyboards), toolbar extends itself to search-bar, but as soon as i click back key(which removes the cursor from the search bar), toolbar goes to normal size.
Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <com.taadu.slidechat.adaptor.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried to define some numbers in `android:layout_height` of `AppBarLayout` but this makes my tabs go away, but then also toolbar size is not normal, it is always short of it's regular height.

I have searched whole stackoverflow, but couldn't find any relevant data.

Comment: Try to add this on your toolbar: `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear... But if I got it correctly, try to set your `layout_height` to `?attr/actionBarSize`.

Your layout will look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

        <com.taadu.slidechat.adaptor.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```